# React state nested attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing around with a [Fluxxor tutorial (example at the very top)](http://fluxxor.com/guides/quick-start.html) and there's a simple todo list built with React. It's very basic and I wanted to add a simple validation to get better understand of data binding.

```
var Application = React.createClass({
  mixins: [FluxMixin, StoreWatchMixin("TodoStore")],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { newTodoText: "" };
  },

  getStateFromFlux: function() {
    var flux = this.getFlux();
    return flux.store("TodoStore").getState();
  },

  render: function() {
    var todos = this.state.todos;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {Object.keys(todos).map(function(id) {
            return <li key={id}><TodoItem todo={todos[id]} /></li>;
          })}
        </ul>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>
          <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="New Todo"
                 value={this.state.newTodoText}
                 onChange={this.handleTodoTextChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Add Todo" />
        </form>
        <button onClick={this.clearCompletedTodos}>Clear Completed</button>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

So if I want to disable `submit` if the input field is empty, I can compare the value of input with the initial state:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Todo" disabled={!@state.newTodoText}/>
```

Now I want to disable `Clear Completed` until at least one TodoItem is marked as completed. When this happens `this.state.todos` is updated with a with a `completed` key set to `true` and it's available in my application component:

```
Object {todo: Object}
  todo: Object
    complete: true
    id: 1
    text: "text"
```

How I should handle this logic? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function which returns the number of completed todos in your object.

```
countCompleted: function(todos) {
  var todoKeys = Object.keys(todos);

  var completed = todoKeys.filter(function(key) {
    var todo = todos[key];
    return todo.complete;
  });

  return completed.length;
}
```

Then call that function from render to conditionally disable the button.

```
<button
  onClick={this.clearCompletedTodos}
  disabled={this.countCompleted(todos) > 0}>
  Clear Completed
</button>
```